# I receive SIGABRT when working with NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsuserdefaults

The following line sometimes throws SIGABRT:

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

I have not idea why it happens.
By the way, the app is multithreaded.

Comment: In which thread do you send that message?

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults is thread safe, that's not the problem. You are over releasing some object in your defaults and synchronize is crashing when it finds it.

Comment: No, this is probably not the reason.

Comment: Can you enable NSZombieEnabled and see what happens? Is there any particular reason why you are running synchronize manually?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685464/nszombieenabled-hides-exc-bad-access-error-entirely/2695707#2695707 and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190227/how-do-i-set-nszombieenabled-in-xcode-4/4917557#4917557

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you added a Key Value Observer on a preference and did not implement

`-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context`